# Dictionaries in Swift Functions

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm new to Swift, and I'm expected to know the entire language with its advanced complexities in a week! I need to write a function which has a dictionary as an argument, and the function returns a string. For example, I want to use `let pricemeal = ["name": "Burger", "price": "4"]` and when I call the function `price(price meal)` I get `4` in return. I declared the function as follows:

```
func price(dictionary: [name:String, price:String]() {
```

The function header is incorrect, and I can't find resources on the internet for example functions that take a dictionary as an argument. Any examples or solutions would be helpful.

Comment: By the way, keeping objects as dictionaries is wrong. Immediately when you get a dictionary like this, you should parse it into a custom object. Then you won't need trivial functions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. All you should need is this:

```
func price(dictionary: [String : String]) {
```

Comment: If someone if good in Swift, can you tutor me? I can pay you money on PayPal. Please email me if you are interested. My email is phantomy1982@gmail.com

Comment: @Mike, if you're willing to spend money I suggest you either buy a good book or a monthly subscription to a tutorial website.

Answer (score 0):

sine you want to return a string this is the completely syntax of it

```
func someFunc((theDictionary : [String : String]) -> String)
{
//function body

return //string
}
```

keep in mind that if you want to access a value of the dictionary you can just go as

```
var someDictionary = ["aKey" : "aValue"]
someDictionary["akey"]//this will print the value of aKey. Careful it returns an optional cause there might not be a value for this key:)
```

Comment: So, how about if I want to have three keys and three values such as for example, name, price, and quantity, and I want to return the total price which is price * quantity, how do I access the second item in the dictionary. So, is it accessed by index? Also, what if a key was missing a value.. in that case I want to return nil. I guess I can do that with optional.. I've been reading a lot but there are not a lot of resources on Swift...

Comment: if for example you try to access a key named length in your dictionary it is going to return nil so you are safe with that. to access the value yes indexing is viable for example for a dictionary of type [String : Int] its totally viable to say someDictionary["price"] * someDictionary["price"]. But if i think correct what you want to make you really don't need a dictionary, cause every key of a dictionary can only save ONE value. The name key  can only appear once so does the price key